# Universal clipboard alert on app launch

Tags: ios

With some probability when launching the app the universal clipboard alert appears.

[image]

I'm not listening any clipboard notifications. In the app I only set strings to clipboard as `UIPasteboard.general.string = X`. My questions are:

- how can I disable showing this alert?
- what is happening at this moment, when in theory this alert appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in GPPDeepLink initialization. The app on launch called `GPPDeepLink.readAfterInstall()`. After removing this line the alert does not appear anymore.